# wrong output in loading gray images in matplotlib

Tags: opencv, matplotlib

I have been working on ocr, so I need to load images and convert it to gray scale
I tried to load the image as below

```
filename = "sample.jpg"
image = cv2.imread(filename)
plt.imshow(image)
```

it gave image which is what I need.

when I tried to load as grayscale image as

```
filename = "sample.jpg"
image = cv2.imread(filename,0)
plt.imshow(image)
```

the loaded image wasn't grayscale.
Any sort of help is appreciated, thank you.
link to image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1i44.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was enough just to look for what matplotlib display a grayscale image in color ..., there are plenty of forums on that.
[See this explanation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html)

Here is the correct code:

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = "image.jpg"
image = cv2.imread(filename, 0)
plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

just use opencv its faster:

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('yourImg.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('Original image',image)
cv2.imshow('Gray image', gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```